# How to get AVERAGE from two tables using JOIN in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a table structure as given below, i want to get the avg rating of each post, for that i am writing following query to join and get records but it gives syntax error :

```
$this->db->select($query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM post,AVG(`rating`) AS `avg_rating` JOIN review ON `post`.`id` = `review`.`post_id`');
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dint use group by and to execute use like this $this->db->query(" your sql");

```
$this->db->query('select rating.post_id,avg(rating.rating) as `avg_rating` from rating,post where rating.post_id=post.id group by rating.post_id');
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems found:

- your code is incorrect. Codeigniter expects a certain format when it comes to creating queries, follow the [manual here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) to understand in more depth.
- you are getting the average rating but you are not grouping thus ending with one result, rather than one result per each post.

This is how I would rewrite your model method:

```
function getRatingInfo(){
    $this->db->select("*, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating");
    $this->db->from("post p");
    $this->db->join("review r", "p.id=r.post_id");
    $this->db->group_by("post_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```